# How to separate fields from a big OCR multiline String?

Tags: java, ocr

I am working on OCR based Android App,getting this text as String from the Image dynamically (getting the text in Horizontal Direction from the Image)

Text from Image:

"Parts Cost Engine Oil and Oil Filter Replacement Rs 10000 Air Filter Rs 45000 Cabin AC Micro Filter Rs 40000 Pollen Filter Rs 12000 AC Disinfectant Rs 30000 Fuel Filter Rs 60000 Spark Plug Set Replacement Rs 10000 Body Wash, Basic Clean 8, Engine Degrease F2s 30000 Body Wax Polish Detailed Rs 70000 Car Interior Dry Clean with Germ Clean Rs 80000 Wheel Alignment 8. Balancing Rs 60000 Brake Pads Replacement (Pair) Rs 30000 Brake Disc Replacement (Pair) Rs 30000 Power Foldable \u0026 Heated Side ORVM Replacement Rs 40000 Battery Replacement Rs 25000 Front Shock Absorber Pair Assembly(Both Left \u0026 Right) Rs 60000 Headlight Assembly (Xenon F\u0027Ius) Rs 15000 Alloy Wheel Set (16 Inch - 17 Inch) - Set of 4 Alloys Rs 12000 Fuel Injectors Replacement Rs 12000 Fuel Assembly (F\u0027ump + Injectors + Fuel Unit + Distributor) Rs 30000 Bumper Replacement Rs 60000 Bonnet Replacement Rs 10000 lntercooler Replacement Rs 40000 AC Compressor Assembly Replacement Rs 20000 AC Condense, Radiator Replacement Rs 10000 Work like Dent Removal with Minor Scratch Repair Work with Paint Rs 18000 Windshield Replacement Rs 35000 Suspension Overhaul (Retro Kit of Suspension including Lower Arm, Rs 20000 Transmission System Failure - replacement (extreme rare cases) Rs 70000 TOTAL Rs 50,00000 00 ".

```
example : 
Engine Oil and Oil Filter Replacement Rs 10000
key = Engine Oil and OH Filter Replacement
value = 10000
```

I need to separate the Parts and Cost(2 columns each) get the values from it and should store it in SQLIte Database Android.I am stuck how to get the values and separate them.

Comment: Hi Pang, Actually I am working on OCR based Android App(Scanning the text horizontally).So I am passing Image to the API and I am getting the response Text as I mentioned above.So I need to separate the Part Name and Part Cost.Please Help me.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer, as I'm totaly unable to figure out what the app should extract from the example string you gave. There are even not some monetary symbols to help for it !

Comment: @Orabîg, Thanks for the response.I have edited the String.Please check it and help me ASAP.

Comment: @Naveenn Please have look at bellow function

Comment: Ok, why didn't you say taht 'Rs' could be a valid separator ? This is such a very important clue, that you don't even bother to tell !!

Answer (score 1):

Android_Dev 's solution is utterly complex. (sorry dude)

This code :

```
ocrText = ocrText.replaceAll(" F2s "," Rs "); // Error in OCR
java.util.regex.Pattern lines = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(.*?) Rs (\\d+) *");
java.util.regex.Matcher matchLines = lines.matcher(ocrText);
while (matchLines.find()) {
    System.out.println("\nkey = " + matchLines.group(1));
    System.out.println("value = " + matchLines.group(2));
}
```

Is doing what you want and prints :

```
key = Parts Cost Engine Oil and Oil Filter Replacement
value = 10000

key = Air Filter
value = 45000

(...)

key = Windshield Replacement
value = 35000

key = Suspension Overhaul (Retro Kit of Suspension including Lower Arm,
value = 20000

key = Transmission System Failure - replacement (extreme rare cases)
value = 70000

key = TOTAL
value = 50
```

(and please, next time, mention the 'Rs' separator. How are we supposed to guess this one ???)

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

As in your case there is no standard format of data (We can't expect that from OCR library) you write your own custom parser. You can use bellow function to parse your data.

```
public static void parseResponse(String responseData)
{
    String SEPARATER = "Rs";
    String SPACE = " ";

    if(data != null && data.length() != 0)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        Map<String,String> keyValueMap = new HashMap<>();

        while(endIndex < data.length())
        {
            endIndex = data.indexOf(SEPARATER, startIndex);

            if(endIndex == -1) // Break loop if Separator not found
                break;

            String key = data.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

            Log.d("", " Key = " + key);

            startIndex = endIndex + SEPARATER.length() + 1; // pluse one for Space character

            endIndex = data.indexOf(" ",startIndex);

            String value = "";

            if(endIndex == -1)
            {
                value = data.substring(startIndex,data.length()-1); // End of the String
                endIndex = data.length();
            }else
            {
                value = data.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
                startIndex = endIndex;
            }


            Log.d("", " Value = " + value);

            keyValueMap.put(key, value);

            startIndex = endIndex;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Android_Dev, will look after it.

Comment: If above code is working for you accept above answer.

Comment: Above code working but the response is not in order.

Comment: can you please look at it.

Comment: May be you can use different data structure other than HashMap which will keep insertion order. Example : LinkedHashMap. Just replace HashMap with LinkedHashMap

Comment: Thanks Android_Dev.

Comment: I cannot accept your answer because my reputation is lessthan 15.